# Rapidxml causing weird problems

Tags: c++, stream, rapidxml

Iam having problem with rapidxml. Code below gives me output: http://pastebin.com/352MxuQY
But when I remove loop or "{}" where Iam appending node I get good output: http://pastebin.com/H0YQGwV1
Why is this happening?

```
rapidxml::xml_document<> andDoc;

ifstream andfile(PATH+XMLNAME);
vector<char> buffer((istreambuf_iterator<char>(andfile)), istreambuf_iterator<char>( ));
buffer.push_back('\0');
cout<<&buffer[0]<<endl; 
andDoc.parse<0>(&buffer[0]); 
xml_node<>* cos = andDoc.first_node("Data")->first_node("Classifiers");
xml_node<>* klda = andDoc.first_node("Data")->first_node("Kldas");

for(int i=0;i<1;i++)
{

    rapidxml::xml_document<> doc;

    ifstream myfile(cPATH+"0\\c.xml");
    vector<char> buffer2((istreambuf_iterator<char>(myfile)), istreambuf_iterator<char>( ));
    buffer2.push_back('\0');
    cout<<&buffer2[0]<<endl; 
    doc.parse<0>(&buffer2[0]); 
    xml_node<>* cl = doc.first_node();
    xml_node<>* asd = doc.clone_node(cl);

    cos->append_node(asd);

    myfile.close();

}
std::ofstream file(PATH+XMLNAME);
if (file.is_open())
{
    file.clear();
    file << andDoc;
    file.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Somewhat late, but here's what I think is happening: RapidXML's `clone_node` doesn't work the way you think it does.

[From the docs](http://rapidxml.sourceforge.net/manual.html#classrapidxml_1_1memory__pool_95c49fcb056e9103ec906a59e3e01d76_195c49fcb056e9103ec906a59e3e01d76), with some added emphasis...

---

**Synopsis**

```
xml_node<Ch>* clone_node(const xml_node< Ch > *source, xml_node< Ch > *result=0);
```

**Description**

Clones an xml_node and its hierarchy of child nodes and attributes. Nodes and attributes are allocated from this memory pool. ***Names and values are not cloned, they are shared between the clone and the source.*** Result node can be optionally specified as a second parameter, in which case its contents will be replaced with cloned source node. This is useful when you want to clone entire document.

---

So, what's happening is that the names and values of the cloned node go out of scope (and are thus lost) when the xml_document 'doc' goes out of scope at the end of the for loop. Given this restriction, I can't honestly see what use `clone_node` is.

I'm not sure how best to fix this - it depends on your real-world requirements, but you might have to somehow keep all source docs in scope until the final output is created.